# ¿Como colocar una variable como patron en el LIKE? SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

es que estoy haciendo un proyecto y trato de hacer un trigger el cual le asigna el número de curso automáticamente.

Este es el trigger que se me ocurre

```
create or replace trigger TG_curso_Auto
before insert on cursos
for each row
declare
num_var int;
begin
    select count(*)+1 into num_var from cursos WHERE siglas LIKE '{VARIABLE EN ESTE CASO :NEW.siglas}%';
    :new.siglas := concat(concat(:new.siglas,'-'),TO_CHAR(num_var));

end;
/
```

Esta es la tabla:

```
create table cursos(
id number(3) not null,
nombre varchar(40) not null,
siglas varchar(7) not null,
estudiantes_inscritos number(2) not null);
```

EJEMPLO:

```
INSERT INTO cursos(id,nombre,siglas,estudiantes_inscritos) VALUES (1,'Bases 
de Datos',MBDA,7); -----> Deberia colocarme MBDA-1

INSERT INTO cursos(id,nombre,siglas,estudiantes_inscritos) VALUES (2,'Bases 
de Datos',MBDA,8); -----> Deberia colocarme MBDA-2

INSERT INTO cursos(id,nombre,siglas,estudiantes_inscritos) VALUES 
(3,'Programación Orientada a Objetos',POOB,8); -----> Deberia colocarme 
POOB-1
```

Muchisimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: qué problema tienes con el trigger como lo estás haciendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer para lograr usar de una forma dinámica la sentencia LIKE es concatenar la variable de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TG_CURSO_AUTO
  BEFORE INSERT ON cursos
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
   num_var NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    --
    SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
    INTO   num_var
    FROM   cursos
    WHERE  siglas LIKE :NEW.siglas||'%';
    --
    :new.siglas := :NEW.siglas||'-'||num_var;
END;
/
```

Sin embargo te recomendaría tener mucho cuidado con el trigger que estas construyendo, ya que estas consultando la misma tabla sobre la que esta el propio trigger, y eso podría generar una mutación del trigger, mira aquí una referencia del tema http://www.exa.unicen.edu.ar/catedras/dbases1/apuntes/Tablas.Mutantes.pdf.